# How to kill all process with given name?

Tags: grep, process, kill, ps

I run command `ps -A | grep <application_name>` and getting list of process like this:

```
19440 ?        00:00:11 <application_name>
21630 ?        00:00:00 <application_name>
22694 ?        00:00:00 <application_name>
```

I want to kill all process from the list: `19440`, `21630`, `22694`.

I have tried `ps -A | grep <application_name> | xargs kill -9 $1` but it works with errors.

```
kill: illegal pid ?
kill: illegal pid 00:00:00
kill: illegal pid <application_name>
```

How can I do this gracefully?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
pkill -f 'PATTERN'
```

Will kill all the processes that the pattern `PATTERN` matches.  With the `-f` option, the whole command line (i.e. including arguments) will be taken into account. Without the `-f` option, only the command name will be taken into account.

See also `man pkill` on your system.

Comment: Assuming `pkill` is installed, of course - on Debian it's in the `procps` package.

Comment: I need to get this tattooed on the back of my hand.

Answer (score 28):

The problem is that `ps -A | grep <application_name> | xargs -n1` returns output like this

```
19440
?
00:00:11
<application_name>
21630
?
00:00:00
<application_name>
22694
?
00:00:00
<application_name>
```

You can use **`awk` to a get first a column of `ps` output**.

```
ps -A | grep <application_name> | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1
```

Will return list of PIDs

```
19440
21630
22694
```

And adding `kill -9 $1` you have a command which kills all PIDs

```
ps -A | grep <application_name> | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 $1
```

Comment: this is perfect I test it on bash script it's kills the processer immediatly with no errors + even if the process is'nt started it shows no errors which is what I want , here example of ffmpeg processer killer , `nano /usr/bin/ffmpegk`   . . . .   `ps -A | grep ffmpeg | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 $1`    . . . .     `chmod    a+rx  /usr/bin/ffmpegk`

Comment: I have a problem with this where I get the output of `kill -9` if no process matches

Comment: Instead of the `grep`, you should be using `awk` to match on the name: `ps -A | awk "\$4 == \"$1\" { print \$1; }"`

Comment: could we use `ps auxww`  instead of `ps -A`?

Answer (score 2):

`killall` can do that.

```
$ killall application_name
```

Comment: Is kill all allowing regular expression in an application name?

Comment: `killall  --regexp "appl.*me"` Though there might be different killall implementations. See `man killall`.

Comment: killall not enough sometimes I need to send it three time to kill the process , and even fail to kill it , the only fast working solution fo me is 
 `kill -9 pid` I think @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski is the best working solution specially for bash scripts .

Answer (score 1):

`pkill` sends `SIGTERM` in default, and in my case `pkill -f <some_pattern>` did'nt kill my processes. I recommend below command for such cases, which worked perfectly for me!

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -f somepattern)
```

I also recommend to see which processes match before running kill command

```
pgrep -af somepattern
```

Comment: `pkill --signal KILL …`?

Comment: I tried pkill -SIGKILL <pattern>, it didn't work. Can you give me a complete example of usage pkill with -9?

Comment: In my Ubuntu `pkill -9 sleep` or `pkill --signal KILL sleep` forcefully kills all my `sleep` processes.

Answer (score -2):

And I have used `-w` flag for `ps` to capture wide output in case not to miss any process name.

```bash
ps auxww | grep -E "[a]pplication_name" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Will return list of PIDs

```
7644
407
406
```

Next, if there is valid output the results piped into `xargs kill -9` command, to kill all correspondings PIDs.

```bash
ps auxww | grep -E "[a]pplication_name" | awk '{print $2}' | ifne xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Why the `grep` instead of using `awk` to do the test more correctly?  `grep` will match names that include the target as substring, for example.

Comment: @TobySpeight sorry I did not understand what you mean by `Why the grep instead of using awk`?

Comment: Two reasons: no need for an extra process, since we're already running `awk`, and the `grep` will match more than we want - e.g. if I search for `emacs`, I also get `emacsclient` processes.  And with a search pattern that matches my username, I get *many* other processes.  Consider something like `ps auxww | awk 'gensub(".*/","",1,$11) == "'"$prog_name"'" {print $2}'` for exact matching.  The whole approach is flawed on platforms (such as Linux) that let applications write to the process name area, anyway.  You're better off installing the `procps` package, which provides `pgrep` and `pkill`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the detailed explaination. But it only finds exact matching process names like you mention. Instead can we apply for sub-matching words like `prog_n*`?

Comment: If that's what you want, just use a regular-expression match (`~`) instead of equality match (`==`).

Comment: @TobySpeight Its best for you to make a answer for `ps auxww | awk 'gensub(".*/","",1,$11) ~ "'"$prog_name"'" {print $2}' | ifne xargs kill -9` :-)

Comment: Not really, because the right answer is to use `pkill`, from the `psproc` package.

Comment: No, don't delete it - there's valuable insight here, and with this comment exchange, it has genuine educational potential.

Comment: Okay I will keep it :-) Thanks for your valuable comments!