# extracting column value from a command

Tags: kill, xargs

I've multiple process of xargs running. I want to terminate them all using kill at once . How to do them ? . So far I've tried this

```
ps -a | grep -i xargs | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill .
```

Comment: Did you try `pkill xargs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill all process with given name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316065/how-to-kill-all-process-with-given-name)

Comment: Thank you . pkill xargs? worked . I'm a noob . Newly learning linux @Kusalananda

Comment: thanks dude @thanasisp .  It worked